# How to import codes in .html file which are placed in a txt file ?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, what i want is this. I have an HTML File and i want the code to load from a text file. So, the browser should get the code from that text file and read it as a part of the HTML code. Here is an example:

Suppose I have an HTML File whose code is :-

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<div src="code.txt"></div> [ I made this code. I know this code does not exist.]

</body>
</html>
```

---

And i have text file named 'code.text' :

```
<h2>Welcome</h2>
<img src="sample.jpg">
<p>This is the paragraph.</p>
```

---

So, instead of writing code in the actual HTML File, i saved the codes in a text file and want to use them whenever i want. I know the following code does not exist.

```
<div src="code.text"></div>

I made up this code just to show what i want.
```

**

> Just tell me the way i can achieve this purpose.

**

Thanks,

Waiting for your answer !

Comment: Is this what you want to do? [w3,js - Include HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp)

Comment: w3.js include HTML will use Javascript and that will decrease the SEO Performance which i do not want. Because the SEO crawlers will not grab that information, here is the link if you want to see :

https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/html-import/

(See the last section of Final Thought)

Comment: So would anything that will include the code during rendering. I am not sure if browser will allow to import from external source without JS (like we are allowed with `img`). If you are looking for a template based approach (during development) then a lot of libraries are available - [eJs templating](https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application), [angularJs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/templates) etc. They allow you to develop in this fashion.

Comment: this is rather a backend appraoch than a front-end one. As the main purpose is to deliver a final code to the use, why you should deliver him a part and then doing a treatement to add the remaining (unless it's an interactive or one page site using tools like Angular)

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but i got the solution. Yo !

Answer (score 0):

I got the SOLUTION.

And the solution is to use "php include".

```
<?php include("code.text"); ?>
```

OR similarly you can use it for other files.

```
<?php include("your_html_code.html"); ?>

<?php include("your_html_css.css"); ?>
```

You can import any code files like this (text,html,css etc.) and the browser will read the codes as a part of the main code.

This way you can use it to create templates so that you don't have to type the same code again and again.

Also, if you intend to make some changes, then the changes will be applied everywhere. This will save you a lot of time if you are creating a blog or if your website has many pages with some same sections.

> **Get the full guide for using this technique of php 'include' here:**
>
> http://www.apaddedcell.com/how-automatically-include-your-header-navigation-and-footer-every-page

Answer (score 0):

You can load the content of this with jQuery ajax. Your div will look like this: `<div id="content"></div>`

And you call the document using ajax:

```
$.ajax("code.text").done( html =>{ $('#content').html(html) });
```

You can view more on http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

**Why not use SHTML?**

SHTML is an HTML file that includes server instructions or server side includes and is similar to an ASP file.

It's embedded in a standard XML comment, and looks like this:

```
<!--#include virtual="../top.shtml" -->
<!--#include virtual="../quote.txt" -->
```

For example, a .shtml page that includes a resource can be as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>My SHTML Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!--#include virtual="content.html" -->
</body>
</html>
```

You can use to include a common header and footer in your pages, so you don't have to repeat code as much, and changing one included file updates all of your pages at once.

Apache can be configured to parse any file with a particular file extension, such as .shtml, with the following directives in the http.conf file:

```
AddType text/html .shtml
AddHandler server-parsed .shtml
```